# Как вставить данные в середину большого файла, который не помещается в оперативку?

Tags: python, файлы

На собеседовании задели вопрос:

> Как вставить данные в середину большого файла, который не помещается в оперативку ( например 100 гб )?

Comment: Вставить или записать кусочек поверх старых данных?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6475328/how-can-i-read-large-text-files-in-python-line-by-line-without-loading-it-into

Answer (score 4, accepted):

есть команда `seek` во многих языках, чтобы писать/считывать из нужного места файла:

в питоне она тоже есть

https://pythonz.net/references/named/file.seek/

кроме того всегда можно решить задачу в лоб и начать считывать файл по частям, записывать по частям, потом записать в нужную часть данные, записать, и дальше опять считывать и записывать файл по частям

но это все таки костылинг, когда есть стандартные функции

Comment: По вашей же ссылке указано, что все изменения в режиме добавления данных не будут зафиксированы. Ответ MaxU более подходит к этой задаче.

Answer (score 7):

Если файл текстовый, то в цикле читаем файл построчно, копируем строки в новый файл (результирующий) и проверяем дошли ли мы до места вставки. Если дошли делаем вставку в новый файл и после этого продолжаем читать построчно и копировать в результирующий файл.

Если файл бинарный, то вместо строк читать можно по кускам указав сколько байт мы хотим прочитать за раз:

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        chunk = f.read(1024)  
        if not chunk:
            break
        # process the chunk of data here
```

Размер куска нужно подобрать так, чтобы место вставки находилось ровно между двумя кусками, а не посередине одного куска данных...